# How to save a form if the fields are separeted by fragments?

Tags: android, forms, view, android-fragments, fragment

I'm building an application to users fill a form. I have 15 questions and I want to divide this questions 5 in each fragment.

The pages are OK and I can fill the fields.

But, on last fragment I want to have a button to save all the data.

Unfortunately, It doesn't work. The onClick function on this button can't access the views from others fragment.

I just want to be capable to save all the form data clicking on a simple button.

Any ideas?

Comment: Create an object all the fragments can access, and store their answers in it.

Comment: @Richard but when I know the correct time to save my fragment data on this object? Is there any "onShiftFragment" trigger?

Comment: I don't want to put a "save data" button on every fragment. I need do that automatically.